# Connecting the HTML input page with p5.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, p5.js

I want to get the data from input tags and use them in the equation.
I have tried a lot a lot of solutions, nothing worked.
I want it to start setup after click one button, and start animate after pressing the other button.

1. press button1
2. load the data from the html
3. set up the canvas using those data
4. execute `draw()` for ever.

I did not find much documentation.

Here is my html:

```
<label class="col-lg-2" for="n4" id="m2">mass sq 2</label>
<input class=" col-lg-2" name="n4" type="number" id="m2" label="mass sq 2" />
<label class="col-lg-2" for="n5" id="r">Ratio</label>
<input class="ana col-lg-2" name="n5" type="number" id="r" label="Ratio" />
<button class="col-lg-2 btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 10%; 
                        height:30px;"> <h3> change </h3> </button>
```

and here is the p5.js code:

```
button1 = CreateButton('submit1');
button2 = CreateButton('submit2');

let digits = document.getElementById('m2').Value;
const timeSteps = 10 ** (digits - 1);
let m1 = document.getElementById('m1').Value;

function preload() {
  blockImg = loadImage('block.png');
  clack = loadSound('clack.wav');
}

function setup() {
  button2.mousePressed(start);
}

function draw() {
  button2.mousePressed(finish);
}

function start() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, 200);
  block1 = new Block(100, 20, m1, 0, 0);
  const m2 = pow(100, digits - 1);
  block2 = new Block(300, 100, m2, -1 / timeSteps, 20);
  countDiv = createDiv(count);
  countDiv.style('font-size', '72pt');
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to wait and create the canvas after the button is clicked? The reference page  calls create canvas and createButton inside of the  setup function. https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas  https://p5js.org/examples/dom-input-and-button.html

Comment: I want the user to give them the feautures of the canva like width and hieght throw the input fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses instance mode to create a canvas with width and height set from user inputs. This allows us to call `createCanvas()` inside of `setup`. The code only allows us to create one canvas but it would not be hard to modify so that multiply canvases could be created, however, we should never call `createCanvas` more than once for each instance of p5.

```js
var canvas = null;
function createP5 (){
  let canvasWidth = document.getElementById("widthInput").value;
  let canvasHeight = document.getElementById("heightInput").value;
  if (canvas === null){
    canvas = new p5(function (p) {
      p.setup = function (){
        p.createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      }
      p.draw = function(){
        p.background(55);
        p.stroke(0);
        p.rect(p.width/5, p.height/5, p.width/5 * 3, p.height/5 * 3);
     }
    }, "canvas-div");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-div">
</div>
<input type="button" value="create canvas" onclick='createP5()'/>
<textarea id="widthInput"></textarea>
<textarea id="heightInput"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a few different questions:

**How do I run code when a user presses a button?**

There are a few ways to do this, but it sounds like you're looking for the **onclick** attribute. You can Google "JavaScript onclick" for a ton of resources.

**How do I run a P5.js sketch from JavaScript code?**

For this, you probably want to use **instance mode** to have more control over exactly when the sketch is created. See [this page](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) for more info.

The best advice I can give you is to [start smaller](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). Start with a simple page that shows a single button that prints something to the console when you click it. Then add a simple P5.js sketch using instance mode. Work forward in small steps instead of trying to do everything all at once.

Good luck.